# XSLT on the placement of a child node and other text

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have to differentiate between three positions of a child node:

```
<a><b>BBB</b> some other text</a>
<a>some other text <b>BBB</b></a>
<a>some other <b>BBB</b> text </a>
```

how do I know if  is at the beginning of the text, or at the end without any text in between?

(xslt 2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for instance write three match patterns

```
<xsl:template match="a/b[not(preceding-sibling::node())]">...</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a/b[preceding-sibling::node() and following-sibling::node()]">...</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a/b[not(following-sibling::node())]">...</xsl:template>
```

to distinguish the tree type of `b` child elements.